# Getting the error as Delegate does not conform to the required protocol, GADNativeAdLoaderDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

While migrating the admob to the latest version, I am getting the error as below. But the NativeAdCell's protocol list have the GADNativeAdLoaderDelegate.

```
<Google> Delegate does not conform to the required protocol, GADNativeAdLoaderDelegate. Add GADNativeAdLoaderDelegate to NativeAdCell's protocol list.
```

How to check the test ads in the simulator?